# Make Rowspan in table tr ng-repeat based on object return from API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I searched so many hours on Google but did not find any related answer. 
All i found with nested object related article. But i need to make rowspan based on a column value from array. What i now have:

[image]

Now i want rowspan dynamically based on CostTypeName.
HTML Partial code:

```
     <tr dir-paginate="item in GetTodyasProjectCostsDetails|orderBy:'CostTypeName':true|itemsPerPage:itemPerPage">

                <td>{{$index +1}}</td>
                <td>{{item.CostTypeName}} </td>

                 <td>{{item.SubCostTypeName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Quantity}} <b>{{item.Unit}}</b> </td>
                <td>{{item.Amount}}</td>
```

JSon from API (console view):

[image]

How can make rowspan based on CostTypeName?

Comment: You may need to "pre-group" your results by CostTypeName/CostTypeId, then perform a series of `ng-repeat`, one for the CostTypeName then another by item. Paging may cause some issues with this however. Do you get more information for the table in an ongoing basis? or just initially?

Comment: Sorry, Don't understand!

Comment: Do you only get data for the table once? or do you get it for example every 30 seconds?

Comment: Once. I gave my console output of the array in image.

Comment: Do you need to use the pagination here? are you expecting large volumes of items at some point?

Comment: pagination is not needed.